# Checking the equality of all values in array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I check the equality of all values in the array in php this way. I could not find how to do this on any web page, if there is an easier method you can write.

```
    $array = array(2, 2, 1);

    $first_value   = $array[0];
    $count_invoice = count($array);

    $i = 0;
    foreach ($array as $item) {
        if ($item == $first_value) {
            $i++;
        } else {
            // Not equal.
        }
    }

    if ($i == $count_invoice) {
        echo "Array equal.";
    } else {
        echo "Array not equal.";
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by _how to do this on any web page_. If you have a running webserver and you try to access a file with this code, it should work without any problem.

Comment: This is working code. I couldn't find this code anywhere, so I wrote it myself and shared it here for people to access.

Comment: Oh, this is not a question. In that case, you might want to first fomulate a question ( read the [ask] section). Then answer your own question with this code. Because it is very unclear if you require assistance or you are looking to help others.

Comment: This is a __question-answer__ site. Do you have a question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's **no need** to count anything. As soon as you see the value, which not equals `$first_value`, you can break the loop:

```
$array = array(2, 2, 2);
$first_value   = array_shift($array);
$allEquals = true;
foreach ($array as $item) {
    if ($item != $first_value) {
        $allEquals = false;
        break;
    }
}

if ($allEquals) {
    echo "Array equal.";
} else {
    echo "Array not equal.";
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have enough points to give points.

Comment: @EnesAltuntas, good job on accepting this answer. While mine was good legibility, this will perform better.

Answer (score 1):

Good job on finding a solution yourself. However, your code is a little convoluted and might be simplified. I understand you don't have an actual question, but you may find my suggested improvement useful anyway.

```
<?php

// Your input array.
$array = array(2, 1, 1);
// Another array, which consists of unique elements.
$uniqueArray = array(1, 1, 1);

// Use array_unique() to remove duplicates, and count the results. If there is more than one value, then the array didn't consist of all unique values.
var_dump(count(array_unique($array)) === 1); // FALSE
var_dump(count(array_unique($uniqueArray)) === 1); // TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you, but if I may make a suggestion, please accept @u_mulder's solution as it will perform better. If you want to thank me, then consider upvoting the answer.